# How can I protect myself against being thrown off the islands?

Tags: magicka

Oh gravity, thou art a heartless bitch achievement; floating islands, in a game where many spells can throw you across the whole screen; there are some sadistic developers working on Magicka, for sure.

I'm at the end of chapter 6, fighting against successive groups of mages, and mostly getting myself voted off the island, in a very direct and painful way. Are there any way of protecting myself against being thrown across the screen and off the island, except throwing everyone else off first?

Comment: While the name of an achievement here, isn't this question more about *not* getting that achievement?

Comment: @Grace But the people searching for an answer to this question already got this achievement, probably over and over and over and over again.

Comment: They probably got it, which probably means they aren't going to search for it. Reverse psychology isn't very popular to attempt on search engines, to my knowledge. I applaud the creativity, but I think it's misleading. I'm not so much a fan of parentheses myself, but there's certainly a more apt direction or expansion you can take while maintaining creative expression.

Comment: Rolling back to the sanitized title for now. [There is a related Meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1746/should-we-excuse-foul-language-in-gaming-questions-if-its-relevant-in-context), but we're getting complaints about the profanity so we should keep it *out* for the duration of the discussion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set up wall spells behind you.

Don't use a shield.

Throw them off before they throw you.

Pray.

Comment: Pray to Random Number God!

Comment: Just to clarify, the shield makes you take massive knockback from physical attacks, but protects you from magical ones. If you're fighting opponents that use physical attacks, it is usually better to forgo the extra protection to avoid getting knocked down so easily.

Answer (score 4):

While I agree with the foreanswerer on some techniques, there's one that works wonders if you have access to it - **teleportation**.

It can be achieved by either the [Teleport](http://www.magickapedia.net/index.php?title=Magicks) spe-- *cough*... *Magick*... or the [Staff of Emergency Teleport](http://www.magickapedia.net/index.php?title=Staff_of_Emergency_Teleport). Since you're in the sixth chapter and the Magick is unlocked in the seventh, try finding a Goblin Shaman for the safety measure this staff provides.

Comment: Luckily the first group of Mages you fight are goblin shamans.  Just be sure to pick up a staff before killing the last one.

Answer (score 2):

In the first battle on the floating islands, kill one of the shamans and take their staff. If you get thrown off now, press the middle mouse button and you get teleported to a random place on solid surface.

A hint for the third island: as soon as you spawn, press E -> right mouse button to create a shield in front of you to avert the first combined arcane blast.

Good Luck :)